# layout animation issues

Tags: android

First, sorry for my english, i'm vietnamese and my english is bad so please don't be mad ok!

hi everyone, i have to create an app with using animation for layout (pushleft and pushright)
this is my code :

```
ArrayList<LinearLayout>linear=new ArrayList<LinearLayout>();
Animation animLeft,animRight;



     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                LinearLayout llayout=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new       LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                lp.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
                llayout.setLayoutParams(lp);
                llayout.setId(i);
                if(i%2==0)
                {
                    llayout.setAnimation(animLeft);
                    Log.d("SetAnimation,Left","i:"+i);
                    llayout.startLayoutAnimation();
                }
                else
                {
                    llayout.setAnimation(animRight);
                    Log.d("SetAnimation,Right","i:"+i);
                    llayout.startLayoutAnimation();
                }
                linear.add(llayout);
            }
```

**//code for animation :**

**+pushleft**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
     </set>
```

**+pushright**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate android:fromXDelta="-100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="300"/>
    <alpha android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="300" />
     </set>
```

---

```
    public void CreateGame(int round)
{

    ///////////Load all method//////////////
    tvarray=TaoTextView(round);
    addTexttoLayoutbyRandom(round, tvarray);

    for(int i=0;i<round;i++)
    {
        Linearcenter.addView(linear.get(i));
        //linear.get(i).startLayoutAnimation();

    }
    ////////////////////////////////////////
    Linearcenter.startLayoutAnimation();
    iResult=RandomRound(round);
    iRound=round;
    //Linearcenter.startLayoutAnimation();
}
```

I set CreateGame in `onCreate()`, pleaze ignore some param extraneous (like round,iRound,iResult ..)
when the application start i just see 1 child layout effect and it's a first layout with `id = 0`
What's wrong??plz tell me why ?

Comment: Does your log run through all ids? Are the rest of the children on the screen and don't animate or is there only one view on screen?

Comment: Yes, log run  through all ids, have no error or warmning. I have a Linearlayout (call linearcenter) on creen, it's not only view, i have some view like textview, button, but i set animation for linearlayout in code.